# angular firebase authentication persistence problem

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

i cannot set persistence by stayLoggedIn boolean because i am getting this error: Class constructor BrowserSessionPersistence cannot be invoked without 'new'

here is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, Persistence, setPersistence, User, UserCredential, browserLocalPersistence, browserSessionPersistence, getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  loggedInUserEmail: string | null = ""
  errorMessage: string = ""
  isLoadingSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false)
  isLoading$: Observable<boolean> = this.isLoadingSubject.asObservable()
  
  constructor(private auth: Auth = getAuth()) {}
  
  async signIn(email: string, password: string, stayLoggedIn: boolean): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const persistence: Persistence = stayLoggedIn ? browserLocalPersistence : browserSessionPersistence
      this.isLoadingSubject.next(true)
      await setPersistence(this.auth, persistence)
      const userCredential: UserCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, email, password)
      this.loggedInUserEmail = userCredential.user.email
      console.log("Successfully signed in!")
    }
    catch(error: any) {
      if(error.code == "invalid-email" || error.code == "invalid-password") {
        this.errorMessage = "Helytelen e-mail vagy jelszó!"
      }
      else {
        this.errorMessage = "Valami hiba történt."
      }
      console.log(error.message)
    }
    finally {
      this.isLoadingSubject.next(false)
    }
  }
```

i tried adding new keyword or something but it just makes more errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually something with my imports wasnt good, but i still dont understand why

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, Persistence, User, UserCredential, browserLocalPersistence, browserSessionPersistence, getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { setPersistence } from "firebase/auth"
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from "rxjs"
```

if i import setPersistence from firebase/auth instead of @angular/fire/auth it works just fine